# Why I'm getting invalid hook call using Nav tag?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, nav

New React user here. I'm trying to make my first Navbar with React and getting this error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I tried to execute `npm i -S react react-dom` and also check that I'm executing the Hook correctly (understanding this concept yet, sorry). My current code is very simple:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Nav } from './NavbarElements';
    
    const Navbar = () => {
        return (
           <Nav>
      
           </Nav> 
        );
    };

export default Navbar;
```

Why I'm getting this error with `Nav` tag? The element Nav is declared in `NavbarElements.js`:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Nav = styled.nav`
    background: #000;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1rem;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;

    @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
        trasition: 0.8s all ease;
    }
`;
```

Moreover, I'm using React to make the front part of a DApp (blockchain App). I have my file main file `App.js` (which's kinda big):

```
class App extends Component {
  state = { storageValue: 0, web3: null, accounts: null, contract: null };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      // Get network provider and web3 instance.
      const web3 = await getWeb3();
      // Use web3 to get the user's accounts.
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

      // Get the contract instance.
      const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
      const deployedNetwork = SimpleStorageContract.networks[networkId];
      const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
        SimpleStorageContract.abi,
        deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,
      );

      instance.options.address = "0xA65990EC0CA555d2eCDD1d84E9D1397CFA967E60"

      // Set web3, accounts, and contract to the state, and then proceed with an
      // example of interacting with the contract's methods.
      this.setState({ web3, accounts, contract: instance }, this.runExample);
    } catch (error) {
      // Catch any errors for any of the above operations.
      alert(
        `Failed to load web3, accounts, or contract. Check console for details.`,
      );
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  runExample = async () => {
    const { accounts, contract } = this.state;

    // Stores a given value, 5 by default.
    await contract.methods.set(25).send({ from: accounts[0] });

    // Get the value from the contract to prove it worked.
    const response = await contract.methods.get().call();

    // Update state with the result.
    this.setState({ storageValue: response });
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.state.web3) {
      return <div>Loading Web3, accounts, and contract...</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <Navbar />
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And, the error is on the line `this.setState({ web3, accounts, contract: instance }, this.runExample);`. My question is: Am I declaring my react "interface" in a bad place? It's after `render()` instruction (at the end of the file), where I thought it is. But, the point is that I'm getting that error only when I use the `Nav` tag. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I don't see any hook in this code at all. What is the exact error message and stack trace that goes with it? paste it as text in your question.

Comment: Furthermore, the code you've posted seems to have no errors: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ingrid?file=src%2FApp.js I think your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @AlexWayne really appreciate your effort. I tried to reduce the problem and copied just a part of the code. Sorry, I've updated it.